How do you make reference to this note in a relative way?
Me and my band have an intermdiate knowledge of musical theory, please look at this image to see how we reference each note. In a C minor context:

As you can see, there we have a way to reference all of the notes within a minor scale, what you might also notice is that we have no name for C#, I've thought of a couple of ideas:

2nd flat
1st sharp
augmented 1st?
diminished 2nd?

I'm not convinced by any of these, plus the idea of saying flat or sharp might confuse whoever im mentioning this to, because they might think im making reference to the scale while I only want to reference a semitone up from the tonic.
TLDR: Whats a shorthanded way to reference a C# when on Cm without mentioning notes, flats or sharps?
EDIT: Current candidates:

Phrygian 2
Neapolitan
Diminished 2nd
Supertonic Flat
Half tonic
Augmented Tonic

I know the correct way to reference it would be "minor 2nd" but I don't want to confuse beginners/intermediate players making them think im making reference to the scale.

You included the term diminished 2nd on the list of name candidates for C♯ when referencing to the C minor scale root, C. But the diminished 2nd of C is the pitch D♭♭, which is enharmonic to C in 12-TET, not C♯. The correct term (in 12-TET only) would be the minor 2nd. The minor 2nd of C is the D♭, which is enharmonic equivalent to C♯ in 12-TET.

"I don't want to confuse beginners/intermediate players making them think im making reference to the scale": you can just point out to them that major and minor intervals don't take their names from the scales; the scales take their names from the size of their third degree.  Also, C sharp is not a minor second above C; it's an augmented unison.

The flat-two is sometimes referred to as the Neapolitan. In music theory, this has a more specific meaning about how the b2 is being used, but for your purposes, it should be an unambiguous way to refer to that pitch.
Another option, since your naming is scale based, would be to call it the Phrygian Two. The phrygian mode is similar to minor, except with a flatted two. Thus:

1  2  3 4 5  6  7 1 (major)
1  2 b3 4 5 b6 b7 1 (minor)
1 b2 b3 4 5 b6 b7 1 (phrygian)


C♯ may be called the raised tonic.  It can also be called the (secondary) leading tone to the supertonic or to the second degree of the scale.
D♭ is a minor second above C sharp.  You can call it flat 2 or flat 9.  You can also use "lowered" instead of "flat."
You have labeled the tritone as the "blues note" but the correct form of that term is "blue note."
The term "8th" is not used to denote intervals; instead, we call that interval an "octave" (which comes from a Latin word meaning "8th," but still we don't call it an "8th").
